# Converting numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some SQL query output for low disk space. It is displayed in MB, such as 1342 MB

I would like to convert this to GB and if possible in a decimal format such as 1.3 GB. Any suggestions?

Edit: I'm using MS SQL 2008. And I should have given way more info in my original post. Sorry. This is report in Lansweeper. Below is the current report query.

```
    Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tsysOS.OSname As [OS Name],
  tblAssets.Description,
  tblDiskdrives.Caption As [Partition],
  Cast(Cast(tblDiskdrives.Freespace As bigint) / 1024 / 1024 As numeric) As
  [Free (in MB)],
  Cast(Cast(tblDiskdrives.Size As bigint) / 1024 / 1024 As numeric) As
  [Total Size (in MB)],
  tblDiskdrives.Lastchanged As [last changed],
  tsysOS.Image As icon
From tblAssets
  Inner Join tblDiskdrives On tblAssets.AssetID = tblDiskdrives.AssetID
  Inner Join tblOperatingsystem
    On tblAssets.AssetID = tblOperatingsystem.AssetID
  Inner Join tblComputersystem On tblAssets.AssetID = tblComputersystem.AssetID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode
Where Cast(Cast(tblDiskdrives.Freespace As bigint) / 1024 / 1024 As numeric) <
  5120 And Cast(Cast(tblDiskdrives.Size As bigint) / 1024 / 1024 As numeric) <>
  0 And tblComputersystem.Domainrole > 1 And tblDiskdrives.DriveType = 3 And
  tblAssetCustom.State = 1
```

Comment: divide it by 1024?  You may want to specify which database you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(1342/1024.0 as numeric(10,1))
```

Note:

- the `.0` part at the end of the `1024.0` expression is very important.  Without it, you'll get the wrong result.
- Casting as `numeric(10, 1)` takes care of the rounding properly.

Comment: Thanks davetek! Adding the .0 in my current query did exactly as I needed. Which was strange, because I also tried changing BigInt to Float and Numeric to Decimal(5,1). But that did not make any change. If I have it as Float, is there a reason why the .0 would be needed?

Comment: Yes, casting as `float` would also work.  But your other problem would have been your cast as `numeric` (without any decimal digits specified) at the end.  That's why you need to cast as `numeric(n, 1)`.

Comment: btw, this `select cast(cast(1342 as float)/1024 as Decimal(5,1))` works fine too.  I guess you never tried both `float` and `decimal(5,1)` at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
create function dbo.MbToGbString (@mbValue int) returns varchar (10)
as
begin
    return left (round (@mbValue / 1024.0, 1), 3) + ' GB' 
end
go


select dbo.MbToGbString (1342)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL:

```
select pg_size_pretty( megabyteValue * 1024 * 1024 );
```

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @SQLPolice thanks! I posted this answer before he bothered to mention which db he was using